# Automatically load web application on start-up and make full screen

Tags: google-chrome

I've built a web application that runs accross 6 screens with 2 computers both running WIndows 7. The application is on a local linux server and is viewed in google chrome. Each computer loads 3 shortcuts in the startup folder that corresponds to a view of the application, automatically opening in the screen it was last open in.

The screens are arranged in order so that items pass between the screens in a conveyer belt fashion.

This sort of works, but it allows people to close the windows and move things about. Is there any way to lock a browser window to an external screen on startup in full screen mode?

Comment: I suggest that since this is a question about a web browser and not a web app it should be on [su].

Comment: yes I agree, thank you for moving it, I am still relatively new to the exchange.